# Repositories error

Tags: apt

I was using 14.04 beta, When the stable release rolled out, I thought that it might update to stable but now i keep getting these messeges with sudo apt-get update, and a similar one with synaptic

```
    Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty Release.gpg
    Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty Release
    Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty/main amd64 Packages
      Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
    Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
      Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
    Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty/main i386 Packages
      Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
    Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty/restricted i386 Packages
      Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
    Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty/main Translation-en_US
    Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty/main Translation-en
    Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
    Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326) trusty/restricted Translation-en
    Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
    Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
    Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
    Get:1 https://download.01.org trusty InRelease                                 
    Ign https://download.01.org trusty InRelease                                   
    Get:2 https://download.01.org trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex             
    Ign https://download.01.org trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex               
    Ign https://download.01.org trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                
    Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
    Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
    Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
    Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
    Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                         
    Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
    Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
    Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                        
    Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease                        
    Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
    Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
    Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                       
    Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                     
    Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                      
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release.gpg                      
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release                           
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                         
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release                          
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release                          
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                              
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                        
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                          
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                        
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
    Hit https://download.01.org trusty/main amd64 Packages                         
    Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
    Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
    Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en_US              
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
    Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages    
    Hit https://download.01.org trusty/main i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
    Get:3 https://download.01.org trusty/main Translation-en_US
    Ign https://download.01.org trusty/main Translation-en_US                      
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
    Ign https://download.01.org trusty/main Translation-en     
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
    Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease   
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
    Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
    Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US
    Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
    Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
    Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]
    Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [34.9 kB]
    Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages [63.9 kB]
    Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
    Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]
    Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages [35.2 kB]
    Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages [60.8 kB]
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en
    Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                    
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en_US
    Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en_US
    Fetched 198 kB in 49s (3,992 B/s)
    W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
    W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

    W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

    W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

    W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20140326)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_` this error will still appears if you failed to comment out the corresponding CDROM line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command line in Terminal:

```
sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe restricted multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I don't know how about adding the universe,restricted,multiverse repositories will solves his problem.

Comment: well I don't know how this solved it but atleast now I am not getting the cd-rom error, Now I am getting something about a public key authentication "NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366"

Comment: @nabeel: It's a different problem. Run this command to fix the key problem:  `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A902DDA375E52366`
In future, please use `y-ppa-manager` from Ubuntu Software Center when you want to add PPAs to Ubuntu.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: His `sources.list` is wrecked. So resetting it to default fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just comment-out the  line which consists of `cdrom:` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file,

```
sudo sed -ri '/cdrom\:/ s/^(.*)$/#\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then update all the repositories,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar problem with me accidentally deleting old ppa's. I issued the following command and it restored my ppa's and allowed me to update using `sudo apt-get update`. The following command is:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A902DDA375E52366
```

Once that was done i was able to sudo apt-get update once again. Hope this helps someone.