# Getting 404 not found errors when doing `sudo apt-get update`

Tags: 14.04, apt

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

I am getting the following errors when doing `sudo apt-get update`,  I have tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as recommended [here](https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/) but nothing seems to fix the issue.  It appears from reading other questions relating to this issue that the Ubuntu version was no longer supported but I am running the latest version of Ubuntu.

```
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                    
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                   
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release                        
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release                       
Hit http://apt.insynchq.com trusty InRelease                                   
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main InRelease                                   
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/non-free amd64 Packages                     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_AU                 
Hit http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/contrib amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main Release                                     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_GB                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_AU           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_GB           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_AU           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/non-free i386 Packages                      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_GB           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_AU             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_GB             
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
Hit http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/contrib i386 Packages                       
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_AU                         
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources            
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources              
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                         
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en           
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_AU                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                           
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_GB                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/contrib Translation-en_AU                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/contrib Translation-en                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/contrib Translation-en_GB                   
Ign http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/non-free Translation-en_AU                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/non-free Translation-en                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://apt.insynchq.com trusty/non-free Translation-en_GB                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com main/universe amd64 Packages                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com main/restricted amd64 Packages                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com main/multiverse amd64 Packages                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_AU                     
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com main/universe i386 Packages                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com main/restricted i386 Packages                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_GB                     
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com main/multiverse i386 Packages                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_AU                     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/multiverse Translation-en_AU                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/multiverse Translation-en                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_GB                     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/multiverse Translation-en_GB                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/restricted Translation-en_AU                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/restricted Translation-en                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/restricted Translation-en_GB                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/universe Translation-en_AU                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/universe Translation-en                     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com main/universe Translation-en_GB
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/main/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/main/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/main/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/main/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/main/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/main/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I have a similar issue on my old PC, that I am about to purge / decommission (*so not urgent to fix*). **I have yet to resolve ..**

Comment: @saiarcot895 yep, added it to the post

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the line that reads `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main universe restricted multiverse` (and the commented line after that, if you wish). Then run `sudo apt-get update`. There should be no errors now.

Comment: That fixed the issue, do you know why?  I did not add that repository myself, I think it was added when I initially installed Ubuntu.

Comment: The syntax (for the default Ubuntu repos) is incorrect. Right after the URL, the version of the distro (`trusty`) usually goes there, followed by the different sections of the repo (one or more is allowed). See the other URLs for the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. I have used your solution and this http://askubuntu.com/a/468062/47992. Problem solved finally. It took me some hours to find this...

Comment: Note that if you used the command in the second solution, you may want to enable/add the bugfix update and security update repos as well.

Comment: I just had to simply `apt update` before an `install`. apparently the repos were out of date (even though the IP pinged)

Answer (score 26):

To change all of your deprecated urls `http://archive.ubuntu.com` to the working urls `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com`

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/:\/\/(archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com)/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This answer is based on https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/

Comment: This answer is intended for releases that are beyond the support cutoff.  In the case of this question 14.04 LTS still is under support.

Comment: @Pylinux I am still facing the issue

Comment: This solution worked for my Lubuntu 19

Comment: I had to use a slightly different command `sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
` as listed here https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-ubuntu-debian-apt-get-404-not-found-repository-errors

Comment: relevant even in 2022. thanks!

Comment: @BrandonCulley's comment worked for me on ubuntu 12.04!

Comment: On Xubuntu 8, you have to also add in us.archive.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 13):

First run `sudo apt-get -y upgrade` to get apt-get repointed correctly.

Then you can run such commands as:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

without getting the "404 Not Found" error.

Comment: This was the best solution for me. The other answers required me to directly modify files that are usually maintained automatically and I wasn't comfortable with that.

Comment: Do you know why it solves the problem tho? Because we are usually advised to run `update` BEFORE `upgrade`

Comment: @lapin I don't know.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Just confirming that this fixed my issue, running Ubuntu in WSL2.

Answer (score 4):

From [this page](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-ubuntu-debian-apt-get-404-not-found-repository-errors):

Run the following command to update `archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` package repository URLs with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

Since the normal Ubuntu releases link to the archive.… and security.… URLs, the support will be removed after their live cycle of 9 months and respective repositories moved to old-releases.….

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Linux Mint additionally requires the execution of this command:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
```

Comment: Thanks , after `2` hours of trying , only your commands saved me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because the distro (disco, not an LTS release) had been EOL'd and had been removed from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists

You could check whether a new release is available:

> sudo do-release-upgrade -c

Comment: @Kurankat It was useful for me because this is one of the first results on Google

Answer (score 2):

I solved similar problem by replacing `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the content of the default file (try [different ones](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu%20default%20sources.list%2018.04))